# Angular Directive warn user of unsaved changes on page unload with custom modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, onbeforeunload

I have a directive that I use that warns the user if there are unsaved changes in a form on the page.

I would like to warn the user with a default browser popup if they try to navigate away from the site or close the browser/tab, but a custom popup if they try to navigate within the site.

I am currently trying to implement a custom modal within the directive that will be able to used anywhere in the project.

Here is what I had originally (functional with default browser popup):

```
.directive('confirmOnExit', function() {
    return {
      link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
        window.onbeforeunload = function(){
          if ($scope.myForm.$dirty) {
            return "You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave the page?";
          }
        }
        $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
          if ($scope.myForm.$dirty) {
            if(!confirm("You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave the page?")) {
              event.preventDefault();
            }
          }
        });
      }
    };
})
```

Here is what I am currently trying to implement - using the native browser popup if the navigate outside of the page or close the browser, but using my own if they stay within the site. (spacing in 'template:' for review):

```
.directive('confirmOnExit', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
      window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        if ($scope.myForm.$dirty) {
          return "You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave the page?";
        }
      }
      $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if ($scope.myForm.$dirty) {
          $scope.showModal = true;
        }
      });
    },
    template: "<div id='myModal' class='modal-background' ng-show='showModal'>
                <div class='modal-window'><div class='btn-group'>
                  <button type='button' class='btn' ng-click='leavePage()'>Yes</button>
                  <button type='button' class='btn' ng-click='stayOnPage()'>No</button>
                </div>
              </div>"
  };
})
```

While I don't get errors in this code, there is no popup with in-site changes.  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see that you injected the rootScope into your directive even though you are assigning to it. Is that a typo in the question? Otherwise, I imagine that would throw an error.

Comment: You can't take any action that would prevent navigation from a custom modal, so I don't see how the user would even see it.

Comment: @Matthew Green, it was a typo. My apologies. It has been fixed.

Comment: @Amy Blankenship, I don't fully understand.  The action that I'm trying to take is to open up a custom modal, then they can choose whether to stay or not.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It makes sense, but I don't think the browsers agree with our idea of what is sensible. I don't think you're going to be able to talk the browser into pausing the navigation long enough to show your modal.

Comment: Oh I see.  Alright.  Thanks Amy.

Comment: @Amy Blankenship, I have restructured my question with your input in mind.  I'm going to try to keep the native browser popup if they try to go back, close the tab, navigate away, or close the browser. But, using the same directive I would like to also have a customized popup for in-site navigation.  How does the code look that I have?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in your controller that cares whether or not showModal is true.

Comment: They only thing with showModal is in the template of the directive above.  So that the template for the directive will only show when showModal is true. Will that not work?